# Security issues after authenticated user has been logged out

Tags: 6, security

I have a `profile information` page that is being displayed for an `authenticated users`. But after I `log-out` as that specific user,and then i click the `back button` of the browser,I could find the `anonymous user` landing on the profile information of the previously `logged-in user`.

How could I prevent such a behavior as I do have some `confidential information` on those profile information page.

Could someone please help me.

Answer (score 3):

Once page is stored in browser's cache, there is nothing you can do about it. It's responsibility of an user who logs in and views confidential information to remove it from device he was reading it on.

You could try to [prevent caching (as described in this question)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28464/how-to-prevent-caching-of-a-page), but all you send to browsers and proxies in that regard is just an suggestion, not an order. It's a good idea to do this, but sadly you can't be sure of it.

You could use javascript to go to another page if logged out user tries to go back to page with sensitive data.

And you can and should use [Secure Pages](http://drupal.org/project/securepages) to enforce encryption and thus prevent proxies from reading you data.

At the end of the day once user will get that data, data security is his problem.

Comment: Almost all browsers respect cache limits, and that's how gmail, Paypal, etc prevents such problems. So cache exclusion would be your first step.

Comment: @AyeshK - **almost** is the key word here. And most of them keeps data in RAM unencrypted anyway, so it can be retrieved - if it hits swap, sometimes even hours after. Of course making it harder to steal data is always good idea, but it's also good to know one's limits.

Comment: taxnx for the info.i have installed this cache exclusion module..and i have specified the page to exclude the cache.But still the data is being shown.

Comment: Have you tried https://drupal.org/node/197786#comment-1817644 as seen in question I linked?